# Reading excel file from a custom path: error `path` does not exist

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to read bunch of Excel files from a directory, which is not the working directory.

I am trying this,

library(readxl)

```
file.list <- list.files(path = "05_TT/Output/", pattern='*.xlsx')
> file.list
 [1] "2022 Apr.xlsx" "2022 Aug.xlsx" "2022 Dec.xlsx" "2022 Feb.xlsx" "2022 Jan.xlsx" "2022 Jul.xlsx" "2022 Jun.xlsx" "2022 Mar.xlsx" "2022 May.xlsx" "2022 Nov.xlsx" "2022 Oct.xlsx" "2022 Sep.xlsx"
```

This means I can read the file names.

However, if I want to read it,

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

It is throughing the following error:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘2022 Apr.xlsx’
```

One workaround is the change the working directory and omit the path argument and after the reading the files, go back to the original working directory.

My question is, is it possible to do it without changing the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - just include the path in your call to read_excel:

```
path <- "05_TT/Output/"
df.list <- lapply(paste0(path, file.list), read_excel)
```

edit: As per moodymudskipper's comment below, another option is:

```
file.list <- list.files(path = "05_TT/Output/", pattern='*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
```

which includes the original path information in the file.list object.

And as noted by Konrad Rudolph, `paste0()` can be unpredictable with file paths.  Instead, try:

```
df.list <- lapply(file.path("05_TT","Output", file.list), read_excel)
```

note: you don't need to use all of these - either the `full.names = TRUE` or the `file.path()` solution should be fine on their own.

Comment: It might be more direct to use `full.names = TRUE` in the list.files() call

Comment: Using `paste0` with paths is fairly error-prone and not self-explanatory; better to use `file.path`.